# Geth transaction pending on Ropsten testnet that will not send

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, ropsten, pending-transactions

On a Raspbian linux system I have been using `geth --testnet --syncmode light` to sync the Blockchain in one terminal and running `geth --testnet attach` in the other, but when the Blockchain is synced I am unable to send a transaction it just stays as pending. This is odd as the same method worked a few weeks ago.

I am connected to several peers (`admin.peers` in the `geth --testnet attach` terminal) who appear not to be mining it.

The transaction is being run with a 60000 gas and 100000 gas price as it had been before and is sending 0.05 Eth from one Ropsten account to another.

Does anyone have any advice for how I can fix this? I have upgraded geth to v19.14 and deleted the chain several times to resync, the block number is the same as the Ropsten one. I have also tried `geth --ropsten --syncmode light` to no avail.

Thanks for any advice as I am completely out of ideas.

Comment: `100000 gas price` - that's an extremely low price; Try to override your transaction (same nonce) with a higher gas price.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any recommendations on the gas price to use? It is definitely syncing with the blockchain as I have successfully created new accounts. I have set the gas price to 1000000 and gas to 200000 but am still not seeing any movement...

Comment: Solved! Increased the gas price further and worked like a charm. Many thanks